# Not able to retrieve data from excel file to SQL using Bulk insert. Bulk Insert (0 row(s) affected). Does it have any reason?

Tags: sql-server, xlsx, bulkinsert

I am not getting any data pulled from my .xlsx file into SQL table when I do bulk insert. This is how my .xlsx file looks

FirstName | Last Name | Code
Jack        Ferguson    101
Alex        Hales       103

My SQL Query is

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MergeSQL](
    "FirstName" varchar(50) ,
    "Last Name" varchar(50) ,
    "Code" float
)

BULK INSERT [dbo].[MergeSQL]
FROM 'C:\Users\ferguson\Desktop\Sample_SQL_Excel_Files\New Folder\File 1.xlsx'
WITH (Datafiletype = 'char',FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2);

Messages window in SQL Server management studio: (0 row(s) affected)

But I have two rows in excel file.

I don't want to change the .xlsx file to CSV or any other format. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well `.xlsx` files are not CSV format so you're never going to be able to read data from them using `bulk insert` with field and row terminators. (They're actually a bunch of folders, .xml files and supporting files inside a compressed archive.)

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way where we can loop through all excel files in a folder and get the data in a single SQL table through a SQL query and not through SSIS?